# Django: How to dynamically load form to current html page

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a simple form

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Track
    fields = ['website', 'keyword']
    labels = {'website': 'Website URL', 'keyword': 'Keyword'}
```

and a view

```
def track(request):
if request.method != 'POST':
    form = MyForm()
else:
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tb_main:index'))    

context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'tb_main/track.html', context)
```

and html form template(track.html)

```
<form action="{% url 'tb_main:track' %}" method='post'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}

 <button name='submit'>Submit</button>
 <input type='hidden' name='next' value="{% url 'tb_main:dashboard' %}" />
</form>
```

I would like to be able to dynamically load the form when a user clicks on a button on the homepage without changing the url. I am assuming this could be accomplished using AJAX but I am not sure how to approach this.

If i just do an AJAX call to track.html the view functionality won't come with it

How can I dynamically load the view & html template to the home page after a button click?

I tried `<button href="{% url 'tb_main:track' %}">load form</button>`

but that doesn't work. Would be happy to hear from some of the more experienced developers on how to approach this. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you're missing here is the JS script to attach to that button click. Something like (assuming jQuery):

```
$('#mybutton').get(
    "{% url 'tb_main:track' %}",
    function(data) { $('#myform').html(data) }
);
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="myform"></div>
<button id="mybutton">load form</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you might achieve this is with JavaScript 
...you could have a function in JavaScript called **include_form** which will be used to include the form inside a div and it might look like this

```
function include_form(){
    document.getElementById("form_div").innerHTML = "{% include 'folder/form.html'%}";

this.location.reload()
}
```